# Could not connect to SMTP host: outlook.office365.com, port: 587; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Tags: java, sockets, socketexception

I have written code that sends email using outlook.office365.com. When I am running the program getting the following error.

> **javax.mail.MessagingException:** Could not connect to SMTP host: outlook.office365.com, port: 587;
>    nested exception is:
>
> **`java.net.SocketException:`** Permission denied: connect

```
private static final String SERVIDOR_SMTP = "outlook.office365.com";
private static final int PORTA_SERVIDOR_SMTP = 587;
private static final String CONTA_PADRAO = "xxxx@xxx.com"; //Cofig  Mail Id
private static final String SENHA_CONTA_PADRAO = "XYZ"; // Password

private final String from = "xxxx@xxx.com"; 
private final String to = "xxxx@xxx.com";

private final String subject = "Teste";
private final String messageContent = "Teste de Mensagem";

public void sendEmail() {
    final Session session = Session.getInstance(this.getEmailProperties(), new Authenticator() {

        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(CONTA_PADRAO, SENHA_CONTA_PADRAO);
        }

    });

    try {
        final Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(messageContent);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (final MessagingException ex) {
       System.out.println(" "+ex);
    }
}

public Properties getEmailProperties() {
    final Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    config.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    config.put("mail.smtp.host", SERVIDOR_SMTP);
    config.put("mail.smtp.port", PORTA_SERVIDOR_SMTP);
    return config;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    new SendAttachmentInEmail().sendEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't have permission for access your email. For example while i try in my gmail account, if i don't open the setting that show at below, i get a authorization failed but if i open the setting, i can send e-mail with your code.

Please check your e-mail permission and settings.

[settings picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIMYL.png)

Comment: After doing above changes still  error ERROR javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Comment: i changed my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks for reply  could you please explain with steps how I can check e-mail permission and settings in office Office 365